# What configuration to do in IDP to initiate SLO and how to consume IDP initiated SLO response in SP using SAML 2.0

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate, onelogin

We build the SSO in my application for login using SAML 2.0. Here I want to build IDP initiated SLO for logout.

Question
 1. What configuration we need to do in IDP to initiate SLO?

2. How to consume IDP initiated SLO response in SP using SAML 2.0?

Please help me

Comment: Can you describe your environment? what software are you using for the IdP and for the SP?

Comment: I am using oneLogin(https://www.onelogin.com/) as IDP and my application as SP. I am using SAML 2.0 for sso.

Comment: Good question. I have reviewed onelogin docs and can't find any information how to initiate logout from IdP side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build both SP initiated and IDP initiated SLO in SP application and based on IDP SLO configuration(third party application), we can enable SP or IDP or Both initiated SLO.

Check more [details](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#single-log-out) about SLO using SAML 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question I would recommend to use [onelogin toolkits](https://www.onelogin.com/resources/saml-toolkits).

You can choose from ASP/.NET, Java, PHP, Python and Ruby. For example PHP toolkit documentation [shows in details](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) how to implement every step of login/logout process. There is a [similar section for Ruby](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#single-log-out).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked Ruby toolkit but i didn't get anything related to       SLO configuration.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to Ruby section about logout. Please check if that will help.

Comment: As for the first question so far I have just found a hack: I went to Settings -> Account settings and set Logout URL to url the initiates SP logout process. 

Do you have paid account on onelogin? I'm wondering that maybe free account has some limitations about SLO.

Comment: I don't have paid account on onelogin. I configured Single Logout URL in onelogin which is direct to SP logout url and i am getting slo SAMLRequest from idp.I tried to decode the response using Onelogin::Saml::Logoutrequest it is raising some error. How to decode the response?

Comment: Use OneLogin::RubySaml::Logoutresponse (see https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#single-log-out)

Comment: And in order to debug, you can review this online tool: https://www.samltool.com/online_tools.php

On ruby, you can review the ruby-saml-example repository, that handle SSO and SLO: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example

Comment: I am using ruby-saml (0.7.2), i am getting SAMLRequest from IDP. I check the idp_logout_request method(see github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#single-log-out)  but in ruby-saml(0.7.2) there is no method called OneLogin::RubySaml::SloLogoutrequest and OneLogin::RubySaml::SloLogoutresponse class so how to decode SAMLRequest and how to send a SAMLResponse to IDP.